# Excel VBA: Overflow error

Tags: excel, vba, overflow

Just started programming in VBA, I have a problem, and i don't know how to solve this. I think everything is ok. There shows Run-Time Error '6' Overflow when i want to run this macro.

```
Sub Działaj()
Dim Tablica(1 To 5000) As String
Dim Dni()
Dim kolumna As Integer
Dim wiersz As Integer
Dim licznik As Integer
Dim PF As Boolean
Dim tmp As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim tmp2 As String
licznik = 2
tmp = 0
PF = False
kolumna = 22
wiersz = 2
Do
    If Worksheets("Początkowe").Cells(wiersz, kolumna).Value <> vbNullString Then
        For i = 1 To licznik
            If Worksheets("Początkowe").Cells(wiersz, kolumna).Value = Tablica(i) Then 'debugger shows problem here i guess
                PF = True
                tmp = i
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    If Worksheets("Początkowe").Cells(wiersz, kolumna).Value = "koniec" Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    wiersz = wiersz + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me where i made a mistake? I would be very grateful.

Comment: One, you haven't set any value in Tablica(i). Second, if you don't find the value koniec, then the loop keep on until you grow out of your integer variable wiersz, around 32k.

Comment: What do you mean saying "you haven't set any value in Tablica(i)", can you give me an example?

Don't worry about "koniec" it will be at the end of all data in all columns.

Comment: Sorry, you were right about "koniec" too :) Thanks.

Comment: you're referencing `If Worksheets("Początkowe").Cells(wiersz, kolumna).Value = Tablica(i)`, but at no point in your code prior to that line do you assign a value to the array, so Tablica(i) at that stage is an empty string.

Comment: Yes for now. I am going to fill that table data from worksheet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't find the value `koniec` before row 32767, your variable `wiersz` will max out. If you want to continue past that, you should redefine it as Long.

You should also provide an exit for your loop, e.g. existing at the last used row. Instead of a `do ... loop`, I usually use the following code:

```
Dim lLastRow As Long, lWiersz As Long

lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, kolumna).End(xlUp).Row

For lWiersz= 1 To lLastRow


Next lWiersz
```

Comment: Yap, thank you, it was right i forgot about "koniec" at the and of table. I cant set "if" to check if cell is empty because there are some cells empty int the middle of table. Thank you again.

Comment: What I usually do in that case is a for...next, rather than a do...loop, see attached example

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace  **Dim object integer to long**

like this

Dim wiersz As Integer    -->>>   Dim wiersz As long

Dim licznik As Integer   -->>>   Dim licznik As long