# Excel VBA - Date loop that adds additional days to each date until end of adjacent column

Tags: excel, vba

Hi the below code works however I keep getting an "Overflow" error in the date column. The Dates should stop producing at the end of the adjacent column (lastrow) however the date keeps going for some reason.
Please not this is only a subset of the rest of my code.

```
Sub TradeDump()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsp As Worksheet
Dim wsc As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim rnge As Range
Dim Rnger As Range
Dim ePlaceholder As Range
Dim dater As Date
Dim lastRow As Double
Dim counter As Integer
Dim howmanytrades As Integer
Dim lasthoora As Double
Dim Clearer As Range
Dim Clearer2 As Range

lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

lasthoora = lastRow - 1

dater = wsc.Range("MonthE")

i = 1
counter = 2
howmanytrades = wsp.Range("G6", wsp.Range("G6").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Do Until i = lasthoora
   For j = 1 To howmanytrades
        If (j = lasthoora) Then Exit For
        ws.Cells(counter, 4).Value = dater
        counter = counter + 1
    Next j
    i = i + input1
    dater = dater + 30
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Might not be related to the problem, but consider using `Long` instead of `Integer` since there is no downside of doing so, and it can hold a larger number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA: Overflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339067/excel-vba-overflow-error)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a difficult time understanding what you are doing in your Do Until loop. Might be better off to use a For...Next. But at the very least, I would change

```
Do Until i = lasthoora
```

to

```
Do Until i >= lasthoora
```

It would save you from somehow skipping the trigger and continuing indefinitely.

Comment: hi @jason97conners still getting the same error. Its occurring at the `counter = counter + 1` code. The code essentially completes the following. But as you can see its currently overflowing.                                      
End Date         CDS Deals
1/20/2022 2000000-001
1/20/2022 2000001-001
1/20/2022 2000001-002
2/19/2022 2000000-001
2/19/2022 2000001-001
2/19/2022 2000001-002
3/21/2022 
3/21/2022 
3/21/2022